# wp7 listbox selected item selects item in another table

Tags: database, windows-phone-7, listbox, selecteditem

Is it possible to have a listbox selected item to display a single item from another table.

Eg, a table exists with a listbox that has ranks and names
I want the selected Item in the listbox to use the name from the selected item to display further information about the player which is located in another table.

Comment: Yes. but what have you tried? what have you got so far? see also http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible by:

```
listboxname.items.add(listbox2)
```